# A gold ring? A door? What am I?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Like my last post, if no one gets this for 3 weeks, I will post the solution.
If no one gets this for 1 week, I will post a hint.

### Here is the riddle:

In Korea, a door as bears fall up.
In America, a greeting, "Hey dude, what's up?"
In Greece, a virgin, fast as an arrow.
In Britain, a spy, fitting in with stealth.

It rotates one-eighty as Caesar shouts
"Keen! Keen! Keen!"
Missing a letter by just one step.
"Just cease, just cease, just cease!"

Controls 70% of the earth,
With some secrets, ready to be unearthed.
The little gold ring spins without a sound.
Around and around and around and around,
While the songs of the holes sing loudly and clearly,
If only, if only, if only

### Now for some things you need to know.

The question is, "What am I?"
Explain all lines if you can.
Lines 2 and 13 are slightly ambiguous.
Lines 7 and 14 are clues to other clues.
Line 8 doesn't matter
Line 1 is the hardest

## Hint

The 4th line merely means that the spy is within the word of what the answer is, and you have to be very creative with it.

Comment: Surely you mean a door*knob*? ;)

Comment: The first line is actually very interesting ...

Comment: Is the 'spinning rings' bit anything to do with [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zI6vrJHf8qo) in 'The Time Machine'?

Comment: @randal'thor It is talking about the little gold ring and not rings

Comment: What is the bounty in this question for if there is already been an answer provided (By the original poster)?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm on a phone, so I don't know how to do spoilers.
Can somne please add spoilers for me if these aren't working?
This is super late, too but I haven't had a chance to write the answer.

## Here's the answer that you've been waiting for.

... hopefully

The answer is:

> The moon.

Explanation:

In Korea, a door as bears fall up.

> The word for door, 문, sounds like "moon" and is 곰, or bear, upside down.

In America a greeting, "Hey dude, what's up?"

> The moon is up.

In Greece, a virgin, fast as an arrow,

> Artemis is the god of the moon

In Britain, a spy flitting in with stealth.

> This one was a slight stretch. 007 happens to look like oon.

The next paragraph is derived by the following steps:

> You take the word "moon" and flip ur upside down top make "uoow"

Then,

> Then you put it in a caeser cipher, ROT16, to get "keem".

So,

> He misses "keen" by one step.

Controls 70% of the earth.

> The tides are controlled by the moon, and the ocean covers 70% of the earth.

With some secrets ready to be unearthed.

> We continue to look for more information on the moon.

The little gold ring spins without a sound, around and around and around.

> The bright part of the moon phases spin around and around.

While the songs of the holes sing loudly and clearly, If only, If only, If only.

> In Holes by Louis Sachar, there is a song that ends like "If only, If only, If only." The word before this is "moooooooooooooooooooooooooooon".

## And there you have it,

the answer.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is _brilliant_!

Comment: @randal'thor I think the down votes are because of how obscure and tenuous some parts of the answer are from the riddle. I.E In Korean how we are to know that door sounds like moon, or how "What is up?" - The moon; The moon is only 'up' in relation to your position during certain times or how the 7 in 007 is to be interpreted as an 'N'.. That being said, I would rather save my rep and just explain in a comment about the mistakes, rather than have the poster guess as to why/how people don't like their post

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I got so far. Sounds like:

> Artemis

In America, a greeting, "Hey dude, what's up?"

> Artemis sounds like "What time is (it)?"

In Greece, a virgin, fast as an arrow.

> Obvious Artemis reference.

In Britain, a spy, fitting in with stealth.

> An American spy (but working for Britain) named Artemis by the Germans (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Hall)

It rotates one-eighty as Caesar shouts

> Must be Caesar cipher rotated 180 degrees i.e. ROT13

Comment: Hate to sink your boat, but you answered the actual meaning of only one line in that riddle. I promise, you the answers are actually really obvious, it just requires lateral thinking.

Comment: Must be the last line, I guess?

Comment: Nope, the really obvious one (Artemis)

Comment: @McMagister Does it help you in any way that 문 = door and 곰 = bear? The answer surely can't plainly be language.